# What is the difference between block() , subscribe() and subscribe(-)

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

```
Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(10)).map(d -> {
            System.out.println(d);
            return d;
        }).block();
```

**output** : 0

Not able to see any output on console when I am calling with `subscribe()` or `subscribe(-)` methods instead of `block()`

```
Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(10)).map(d -> {
        System.out.println(d);
        return d;
    }).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Do we need to use only `doOnSubscribe(-)` after this `Mono.delay(-)` method?

```
 Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(10)).doOnSubscribe(s -> {
        System.out.println("its printing doOnSubscribe");
    }).map(d -> {
        System.out.println(d);
        return d;
    }).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

**output** it's printing `doOnSubscribe`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your `block()` call explicitly holds the main thread until the publisher completes. By the time it's completed, it's executed the `map()` call, therefore printing the value.

Your `subscribe()` call on the other hand asynchronously executes the `Mono` on a separate scheduler, leaving your main thread to complete. Since the scheduler used by default uses daemon threads to execute your subscription, your program won't wait for it to complete before terminating.

If you introduce a delay long enough for the `Mono` to complete, you'll see the result you expect:

```
Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(10)).map(d -> {
    System.out.println(d);
    return d;
}).subscribe(System.out::println);

Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
```

`0` is then printed twice, once for the `map()` call and once by the `System.out::println` being used as a consumer.

In a real world use case you obviously won't just put in arbitrary `sleep()` calls - a `CountDownLatch` would be a more sensible choice:

```
CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);
Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(10))
        .map(d -> {
            System.out.println(d);
            return d;
        })
        .doOnTerminate(() -> cdl.countDown())
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
cdl.await();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @michael-berry. Its very useful for my requirement.

Comment: In this case the CountDownLatch solution is equivalent to calling a simple `block()`, except that in the above code the error is lost unless we explicitly specify an error handler, in case of `block()` the error is automatically thrown by reactor.

Comment: Hi Michael, subscribe() will execute my code in which thread? I mean elastic/boundedElastic etc?

Comment: @MartinTarjányi In this specific case, I guess it is, indeed. But knowing about CountDownLatch was really helpful to me in a scenario where I have multiple subscriptions, and I needed to make sure all of them finished before continuing. And I couldn't just block, otherwise it would block on the first subscription before starting the other ones in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

To add what @MichaelBerry said in his excellent answer, and maybe to make it simpler:

The main difference is that `subscribe()` just "starts the whole computation" and doesn't wait (by contract) for its result. The computation may run in *any* other thread or even multiple threads. It may sometimes run only in the calling thread itself, which then looks like the same as `block()`. However, this is *not by contract*.

In contrast to `block()`, which *by contract* starts the computation ***and*** waits until it finishes.

You may also read my description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78023730/2886891) to understand why sometimes `subsribe()` and `block()` might give the same result.