# Reactor fireAndForget Mono pass context

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am trying to pass subscriber `Context` to the `fireAndForget` method which is called inside the `doOnNext`. The `fireAndForget` is run also async non-blocking. How this context might be passed so the value for "key" is present? When I run the following test it passes. However, in the logs I can see that for both `doOnNext` I get:

> reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Context is empty

```
@Test
void shouldPassContextToFireAndForget() {
  final Mono<String> helloWorldMono = Mono.just("hello")
      .doOnNext(this::fireAndForget)
      .doOnNext(name -> Mono.deferContextual(contextView -> fireAndForget(contextView, name)).subscribe())
      .flatMap(name -> Mono.deferContextual(contextView -> Mono.just(name + " " + contextView.get("key"))))
      .contextWrite(Context.of("key", "world"));

  StepVerifier.create(helloWorldMono)
      .expectNext("hello world")
      .verifyComplete();
}

private Mono<String> fireAndForget(ContextView context, String name) {
  return Mono.just(name)
      .flatMap(value -> Mono.deferContextual(contextView -> Mono.just(value + contextView.get("key"))))
      .contextWrite(context);
}

private void fireAndForget(String name) {
  Mono.just(name)
      .flatMap(value -> Mono.deferContextual(contextView -> Mono.just(value + contextView.get("key"))))
      .subscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Context` is a subscribe-time concept. There are two possible approaches.

You can expose the `ContextView` at the middle of the chain using [`transformDeferredContextual`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#transformDeferredContextual-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```java
 final Mono<String> helloWorldMono = Mono.just("hello")
            .transformDeferredContextual((original, cntx) -> original.doOnNext(name-> fireAndForget(cntx, name).subscribe()))
            .flatMap(name -> Mono.deferContextual(contextView -> Mono.just(name + " " + contextView.get("key"))))
            .contextWrite(Context.of("key", "world"));
```

Alternatively, you could take advantage of `Mono.deferContextual` in order to expose the `ContextView` at the start of the chain like this:

```java
 final Mono<String> helloWorldMono = Mono.deferContextual(context ->
        Mono.just("hello")
            .doOnNext(name -> fireAndForget(context, name).subscribe())
            .flatMap(name -> Mono.just(name + " " + context.get("key")))
    ).contextWrite(Context.of("key", "world"));
```

Comment: It's almost good, just if you call **just** `.subscribe()`, you are risking that it will not work as fire and forget, but it may run the "inner Mono" in the same thread. Depending on multiple factors, `.subscribe()` **can** turn into a blocking call. If you want to fire and forget deterministically, you should use `.subscribeOn(...)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/57566465/2886891, https://stackoverflow.com/a/78023809/2886891 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/78023730/2886891