# Spring Webflux Context Propagation in a Mutiny Stream

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, mutiny

**Background:**

I have a Tenant ID that I need to pass around in the entire microservice stack. Much like a trace ID in a telemetry/tracing stack.

In the past, I successfully used `ThreadLocal` to do that, intercepting the value from an HTTP header in a request, and passing it down as a header in internal API calls, broker messages, akka threads, using it wherever it was needed, e.g. in a DB driver

**Problem:**

Now, I need to do the same in a reactive WebFlux microservice with Mutiny.

I can intercept the value in a WebFilter and attach it to as a Reactor Context Value, like so:

```kotlin
    override fun filter(
        serverWebExchange: ServerWebExchange,
        webFilterChain: WebFilterChain,
    ): Mono<Void> {
        return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange)
            .contextWrite({
                val ctx = it.put("tenant", serverWebExchange.request.headers.getOrDefault("tenant", "missing"))
                LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass).info("adding ctx to $it: $ctx")
                ctx
            })
    }
```

Which is then propagated downstream and can be used in `deferContextual` or `transformDeferredContextual` in the stream returned from a `Controller`.

Spring does support Mutiny natively, however, the context attached to a `Mono<Void>` in a filter is not propagated to the Mutiny stream.

I can add a context to Mutiny before or after subscription, like so:

```kotlin
multi
            .withContext { t, ctx ->
                ctx.put("z", "3")
                t
            }
            .subscribe()
            .with(context) { LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass).info("item 1 subscribe: $it") };
```

However, if the Mutiny stream is transformed into Flux stream, and then the context is attached, it won't work.

IN short, the following works fine and prints all expected values: `[ctx1, ctx2]`

```kotlin
    Multi.createFrom().items("a", "b", "c")
        .attachContext()
        .invoke { item -> println(item.context().keys()) }
        .map { it.get() }
        .withContext { t, ctx ->
            ctx.put("ctx1", "1")
            t
        }
        .subscribe()
        .with(
            io.smallrye.mutiny.Context.of(
                "ctx2", "2"
            )
        ) { println(it) }
```

However, if the same Multi is transformed to Flux using `MultiReactorConverters`, it does not print context values at all:

```kotlin
MultiReactorConverters.toFlux<String>()
        .apply(Multi.createFrom().items("a", "b", "c")
            .attachContext()
            .invoke { item -> println("multi ctx: ${item.context().keys()}") }
            .map { it.get() }
            .withContext { t, ctx ->
                ctx.put("ctx1", "1")
                t
            })
        .transformDeferredContextual { t, ctx ->
            ctx.forEach { k, v -> println("flux ctx: $k => $v") }
            t
        }
        .contextWrite { it.put("ctx3", "3") }
        .subscribe { println(it) }
```

Above will print only, so only the flux context.

```
flux ctx: ctx3 => 3
multi ctx: []
multi2: []
```

So my question is:

1. Is there a way to propagate context from Flux stream to Mutiny stream?
2. If not, can I intercept Mutiny stream, as it's returned from Controller method, before it's transformed to a Mono in the `WebFilter` ?

**Sidenote, motivation for using Mutiny instead of Reactor:**

Besides of IMO better API (e.g. plugs), I want to use Mutiny instead of Reactor, mainly because in the Reactor, context is not propagated in side effects calls.
In Mutiny we have methods like `call` or `invoke`, that do not change state, but are part of the same chain, which means the context is propagated.

In Reactor on the other hand, we have [a fire & forget pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566465/fire-and-forget-with-reactor/57569541#57569541) ([also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69551316/reactor-fireandforget-mono-pass-context)), which won't pass the context, as it's a separate reactive stack.