# Fire and forget Action on doOnNext in Project Reactor

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a `Flux` stream. For each element processed I want to have an action triggered which is an asynchronous/non-blocking one. For example, a method returning back a `Mono` from a db update.
I want this action to be done on the `doOnNext` block.
I don't want to affect the `Flux`, the processing and the back pressure implemented there.

Supposing `Mono` method to be called is

```
Mono<Integer> dbUpdate();
```

should my `Flux` be like this?

```
public Flux<Data> processData(PollRequest request)
{
    return searchService.search(request)              
                        .doOnNext(data -> dbUpdate(data));
}
```

Or should be as mentioned on a stack overflow [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566465/fire-and-forget-with-reactor).

```
public Flux<Data> processData(PollRequest request)
{
    return searchService.search(request)              
                        .doOnNext(data -> dbUpdate(data).subscribe());
}
```

Won't the above cause blocking issues inside `doOnNext`?

Also which is the most appropriate scheduler to use for this type of action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dbUpdate()` will be ignored if you do not subscribe to it. The following snippet doesn't print anything because `Mono.just("db update")` doesn't get subscribed.

```java
Mono<String> dbUpdate() {
    return Mono.just("db update")
        .doOnNext(System.out::println);
}

public Flux<String> processData() {
    return Flux.just("item 1", "item 2")
        .doOnNext(data -> dbUpdate());
}
```

Note that `.subscribe()` doesn't block your thread, it kicks off the work and returns immediately.

Comment: Thanks Lefteris ;)

Comment: Depending on multiple factors, `.subscribe()` **can** turn into a blocking call. 
See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78143284/2886891

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that if you want to be sure that the fired `Mono` runs in a separate thread, you should use `.subscribeOn(...)` and not just `.subscribe()`.

Compare the two tests:

#### Plain `subscribe()`:

```java
@SneakyThrows
private void sleep(Duration duration) {
    Thread.sleep(duration);
}

@Test
void nestedMonoSubscribe() {
    Mono.just("Main")
            .doOnNext(s -> Mono.just("Nested")
                    .doOnNext(__ -> sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
                    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                    .subscribe()) // uses the same thread, "Nested" is printed before "Main"
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .subscribe();
    sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
}
```

Output:

```
Nested
Main
```

#### `subscribeOn(...)`:

```java
@Test
void nestedMonoSubscribeOn() {
    Mono.just("Main")
            .doOnNext(s -> Mono.just("Nested")
                    .doOnNext(__ -> sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
                    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                    .subscribe()) // uses another thread, "Nested" is printed after "Main"
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .subscribe();
    sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
}
```

Output:

```
Main
Nested
```

See also

- [Fire and forget with reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57566465/2886891)
- [What is the difference between block() , subscribe() and subscribe(-)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59607165/2886891)
- [What is the default scheduler in Project Reactor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71925290/2886891)